# Finder generic icons for music/movies on second drive

Tags: macos, finder, icon, sidebar

I have added an SSD to my iMac with OS X Lion and wanted to reorganise files a little:

- System and home folder on SSD
- Music, Documents, movies on HDD

That's not hard, but when I move the Music folder to Finder's sidebar I get a generic folder icon. Is there any way to get the music icon for that folder (which is on a different drive)? I find it visually quicker and easier to find the correct folders in the sidebar if they have custom icons.

Only solution I found is to use ColorfulSidebar.bundle and get Snow Leopard style color icons (and change them as you like in folders info panel), but I would like to have the newer gray style all over system. The ColorfulSidebar also does not work for in-app file browsing (you always get gray icons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the icons now appear to be hardcoded, it used to be the case that you could just name a folder Movies in your home folder and it would gain the icon but not anymore.

According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380562/adding-buttons-to-finder-toolbar

DropBox are going to pretty extreme lengths to get their icon in the sidebar, using code injection.

In other words, I don't think it is possible I'm afraid.

Comment: Thats what I thought. thanx anyway!

Comment: Not much of an answer I know, but please mark it if you think the topic is complete!